# How to choose the second and third element of the input?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the second and third element when a user inputs his data.
The three options are Top n Editors, Top n Edits, and Top n Articles. (n is a number).
In order to recognize uppercase and lowercase I have lowered any input the user inputs and then tried to retrieve the second element (the number) and the third element in order to proceed with the appropriate functions.
I've been trying to get this in a simple test program:

```
user_input = input('Input command:')
input_lower = user_input.lower()

for line in user_input:
    line_lst = line.strip().split()

print(line_lst[1])
```

But when I do this and for example I input "Hello there world", it only prints: list index out of rage, but if I change it to print(line_lst[0]) it prints: d

I am really new to all this, so thank you for being patient and sorry for my ignorance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for line in user_input:
```

At this point `user_input` is a string, and when you iterate over a string you do so character by character. So for every character in "Hello there world", you do `<char>.strip().split()`, and then assign `[<char>]` to `line_lst`. As `d` is the last character, that is what `line_lst` is finally set to. And since it only has one item, it errors when you try to print the second.

So, just get rid of the loop:

```
user_input = input('Input command:')
input_lower = user_input.lower()
line_lst = input_lower.strip().split()
if len(line_lst) > 1: # check to make sure there's at least as many elements as you expect
    print(line_lst[1])
```